# Determining if ArcGIS Server SOM or SOC is installed on machine?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I need to create a visual map of my current ArcGIS Server system including where software and data are installed. The System comprises of MSSQL, ArcSDE 9.3, ArcIMS, ArcGIS Server 10.0, and various servers which host Server Object Containers, and at least one Server Object Manager.

I can´t see any SOC or SOM in the windows services. Can anyone give me clue how to get this information from my server environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find out one or more of these criteria to determine if ArcGIS Server ist installed

- There is a Service called **ArcGIS Server Object Manager** in the Windows Services Console
- There is a Process **ArcSOM.exe** and one or more **ArcSOC.exe** running on your machine
- Under *%PROGRAMFILES(x86)*\ArcGIS* you'll find an installation of ArcGIS Server
- Use the **PatchFinder.exe** (Included with the servicepacks) or the **[Uninstall Utility](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/uninstall-guides/101FinalUninstallUtilityGuide.html)** included on your ArcGIS Installation Disks which tells you which Type and Version of ESRI Software is installed onto your machine

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen that on Server1 an ArcGIS Server Object Manager is running with an ArcGIS Server SOC monitor. On Server2 there are ArcGIS services running named for example Vector64_sde, Raster64_sde. Would these be sde services that run in the so-called 3 Tier system?

Comment: Probably. 'sdeservice -o list' could confirm this.

Comment: Yes, I have to confess, I didn't mention SDE Service, because we teared them all down and just direct connect. But you are right, that are (now called) ArcGIS Server Basic instances serving data in a 3 tier system. Vince already gave you a hint, that you can inspect those with the sdetools. You can also call `netstat -b` if there are processes listening on port 5151, 5152, 5153, and so on if you want to check if they are active.